# FreeTDS / SQL Server UPDATE Query Hangs Indefinitely

Tags: sql-server, freetds

I'm trying to run the following `UPDATE` query from a python script *(note I've removed the database info)*:

```
print 'Connecting to db for update query...'
db = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={FreeTDS};SERVER=<removed>;DATABASE=<removed>;UID=<removed>;PWD=<removed>')
cursor = db.cursor()
print '    Executing SQL queries...'
for i in range(len(data)):
    sql = '''
        UPDATE product.sanction
        SET action_summary = '{action_summary}'
        WHERE sanction_id = {sanction_id};
        '''.format(sanction_id=data[i][0], action_summary=data[i][1])
    cursor.execute(sql)
cursor.close()
db.commit()
db.close()
```

However, it hangs indefinitely, no error.

I'm new to pyodbc, but it should be setup correctly considering I'm having no problems performing `SELECT` queries. I did have to call `CAST` for `SELECT` queries (I've cast `sanction_id AS INT` [`int identity` on the database] and `action_summary AS TEXT` [`nvarchar` on the database]) to properly populate data, so perhaps the problem lies somewhere there, but I don't know where to start debugging. Converting the text to `NVARCHAR` didn't do anything either.

Here's an example of one of the rows in data:

```
(2861357, 'Exclusion Program: NonProcurement; Excluding Agency: HHS; CT Code: Z; Exclusion Type: Prohibition/Restriction; SAM Number: S4MR3Q9FL;')
```

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to find my issue, but I ended up using QuerySets rather than running an `UPDATE` query.